# How to find error message when NSImage initWithContentsOfFile returns nil?

Tags: objective-c

My app delegate has this method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/mark/Documents/rocket.png"];
    if (image == nil) {
        NSLog(@"image nil");
    }
}
```

The problem is the image is always nil.  I've also tried with a .jpg file.  Is there some way to find out exactly why the method is returning nil?  eg. passing in an error object?

Comment: Why you don't add your image in the xcassets instead of initializing it from path ?

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? If yes you don't have access to the regular documents folder only to the documents folder in the container of the application.

Comment: Yes it was sandboxed - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use the method `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` of `NSData` where you can specify an error object. In case of success you can then create the image with `initWithData:` of `NSImage`. Otherwise you have error information for your message.